# Fix misuse of code formatting in "Comment everywhere" privilege documentation

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, privileges, help-center

The "comment everywhere" privilege documentation refers to the *"add a comment"* link using code formatting.

This may mislead people into thinking that code formatting should be used for English quotes, proper nouns and the like, in their posts. It shouldn't. This is already a problem that gets edited out of a lot of SE posts.

Can we fix it in the documentation?

---

[image: Screenshot of the problem with a nice freehand red circle]

Comment: What would you replace it with?

Comment: @Mast I dunno - quotation marks should be fine? There's an example in my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for noticing the error. I edited the article. Now the phrase formatted as a quote, not as a code.

Answer (score 4):

The help does say: "inline `code in backticks`", so it should follow that example advice when writing the Help. Thus the documentation for "[How do I comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)" should instead be:

---

Click the "[add a comment](//)" link under each post. Comments cannot be multi-line, so simply press enter to submit your comment.

Note that comments support [a small subset of Markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting), so you can do things like: `_italic_`, `**bold**`, `***bold_italic***`, `[chat]`, `[edit]`, `[help/on-topic]`, `[tag:tagname]`, `[meta-tag:tagname]`, and `[named hyperlinks](https://example.com)`.

---

That might offend some HTML purists to have a non-clickable link, but it's literal.
<sub><sub>That took a bit of coding to get it to look correct using the limited Markdown.</sub></sub>

Comment: Code formatting for the Markdown samples seems appropriate, just not for quoting a piece of link text.

Comment: Mm, could be. Link styling on SE is very inconsistent.

Comment: LightnessRaceswithMonica, I swapped out the Markdown as you suggested and expanded the example to include a short list of what seems to be the most frequently used shorthand links.